# Be it that,were to, and should - what were the differences between these conditionals?

Tags: subjunctive-mood, archaicisms

> 1. Be it that John ask me, I shall answer him.
> 2. Should John ask me, I will (or should? or would?) answer him.
> 3. Were John to ask me, I would answer him.

When writers used the foregoing constructions, how, and according to what rule, did the meanings of the other three differ from one another?

Thank you.

-Hal

Comment: Don't use *be it that*. It's the present subjunctive, which except for in the mandative sense, has almost completely disappeared from the English language. And I don't believe it was ever a conditional in the same way that *"Should John ask me"*, *"Were John to ask me"*, or *"If John asks me"* are.

Comment: @PeterShor Note my use of the past tense and the archaic tag.

Comment: Right. But writers still use the other two.

Comment: Right. But I want to know how things were then.

Comment: @PeterShor does "mandative sense" mean, e.g., "it's important that the door be kept closed"?  There are some common exceptions in idiomatic expressions, of course: "far be it from me" and "suffice it to say" are two (sometimes-misunderstood) examples.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a tentative answer based mostly on my intuitions.

I think you have  ordered the sentences according to decreasing likelihood that the condition is satisfied.

1. gives no information either way, similar to modern *in case*; in that respect it's like the subjunctive in Spanish or French, which is why this use of *be* is called the subjunctive.
2. suggests, and
3. claims, that John won't ask.

Though the difference between *should* and *were to* is certainly not very marked. I may have got this part totally wrong.

(Note: The variant of 1 in which the main clause appears to contradict the condition has more or less survived: *all be it [that]* is now spelled *albeit*. Also, *be it that* was often used in the following construction: *be it that A, be it that B*. It means something like: *maybe A, or maybe B. Though I think it can also mean: *maybe because A, or maybe because B.*)

As today, by choosing *will/shall* or *would/should* in the main clause, you could select how strongly to suggest that John won't ask.

Interpreting the choice between *will* and *shall* in the main clause is enormously complicated due to a series of mutually contradictory prescriptive rules fighting with each other and with the natural use coloured by the original meanings of these originally lexical verbs. See [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shall_and_will). Therefore I have so far ignored the fact that you used *shall* (not *should*) in 1 and *would* (not *will*) in 3.

Whether *will* or *shall* is used for pure, uncoloured futurity probably depends strongly on the author and genre in addition to the period. If both 1 and 3 are taken directly from the same source, then there may well be a meaningful difference, though it's not clear what it is. It would be most straightforward if *dutifully* could be added to 1 and/or *readily* to 3 without changing the sense much, but that's not the only option. It really depends on the author's personal style. According to one rule that is sometimes still seen, the meanings of *will* and *shall* are actually reversed for the first person.

Comment: Thank you. Very useful. You answered a lot of questions I had in mind.